# Magento 2 Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

```
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface
```

Found this error while removing deprecation of StockStateInterface for REST API, Does anyone has an idea why this error occurs? Thanks in advance

My code is

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CartItemPlugin
{

    /**
     * @var CartItemExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $cartItemExtension;
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var GetProductSalableQtyInterface
     */
    protected $stockState;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param CartItemExtensionFactory $cartItemExtension
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param GetProductSalableQtyInterface $stockState
     */
    public function __construct(
        CartItemExtensionFactory $cartItemExtension,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        GetProductSalableQtyInterface $stockState
    ) {
        $this->cartItemExtension = $cartItemExtension;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->stockState = $stockState;
    }
   
    public function afterSave(CartRepositoryInterface $subject,$quote
    ) {
        if ($quote !=null) {
            foreach ($quote->getItems() as $item) {
                $productData = $this->productRepository->get($item->getSku());
                $stock = $this->stockState->getStockQty($productData->getId());
                $stockArray = [
                    'image' => $productData->getThumbnail(),
                    'special_price' => $productData->getPrice(),
                    'stock_qty' => $stock,
                    'is_in_stock' => $productData->getStatus() ? "Yes" : "NO",
                ];
                $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();
                $extensionAttributes->setStockItem($stockArray);
                $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            }
        }
        return $quote;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add following code in you modules etc/di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface" type="Magento\InventorySales\Model\GetProductSalableQty"/>
```

Comment: `"message": "The requested qty is not available"`

Comment: your main issue has been resolved for which you added question. your interface is now mapping properly with respective class.
Now "The requested qty is not available" is your logical code error which is usually for products having out of stock

Comment: but if I use StockStateInterface with the same logic it will return quantity of same product .....but not in GetProductSalableQtyInterface

Comment: Their are difference in having quantity shown in admin products grid and actually salable quantity. please study its documentations.

Comment: Gere in this file its proper usage mentioned please follow this file :
vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Model/GetSalableQuantityDataBySku.php

Comment: its means : Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface    look how it will be usable.

Comment: error still occurs after and after instantiate error on allAPI's can you please guide?

Comment: Add above preference at some main module which load all the time or add above preference in all place where its needed

Answer (score 1):

This might come alittle late but i just happened upon this error

With @piotr-rusin answer i was able to figure out that the simple solution in my case was that the `Magento_InventorySales` and underlying modules were disabled in `app/etc/config.php`

This might not be obvious but it's a good debugging step to ensure the modules in question are actually enabled ;)

The shop i was working on had disabled the MSI modules

Comment: totally true, i had the same issue and found that those modules was disabled in config.php

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot instantiate interface...` errors often mean that no `di.xml` preference was found for a given interface.

Does `vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/etc/di.xml` exist in your project?

Preference for the interface that you mentioned is specified on line 36 in that file:

```xml
<preference for="Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface" type="Magento\InventorySales\Model\GetProductSalableQty"/>
```

Comment: preference exist in vendor but still cant instantiate error occurs

Comment: @S.Shah is `Magento_IntentorySalesApi` module enabled?

Comment: yes module is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Run di:compile command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

or you run this  command

```
php bin/magento in:rein
```

will show the issue